# Javascript, remove property from one of two similar objects in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's assume we have this data set:

```
var array = [
                {

                        "name": "a",
                        "group": "a"
                },
                {
                        "name": "a",
                        "group": "a"
                },{
                        "name": "b",
                        "group": "b"
                },
                {
                        "name": "b",
                        "group": "b"
                },
                {
                        "name": "c"
                }
            ];
```

and I want to loop through the array to see if there are two objects have the same group value, then remove the second of them.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length;i++){
                var a = array[i];
                for(var j = 0; j< array.length;j++){
                    if(array[j].group == a.group){
                        var b = array[j];
                        // I need code here to remove property "group" from the variable b only
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

the final results I want are:

```
var array2 = [
                {
                    "name": "a",
                    "group": "a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "a"
                },{
                    "name": "b",
                    "group": "b"
                },
                {
                    "name": "b"
                },{
                    "name":"c"
                }                    
            ];
```

NOTE: I tried `delete array[j].group` but it caused to remove both `group` property from both equal objects. How can I solve that?

Comment: `I tried delete array[j].group but it caused to remove both group property from both equal objects.` because at some point `a === b`. check the way you loop.

Comment: yes, I noticed that thanx @Thomas

Comment: And instead of deleting the property you'd better set it to `null` or `undefined` or `""` whatever you want. JS-engines like Objects with the same signature; *actually it's the same hidden class*, but changing the signature of an Object implies also changing it's hidden class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't compare same items, just shift indexes in inner loop:

```js
 var array = [{"name": "a", "group": "a"},
             {"name": "a", "group": "a"},
             {"name": "b", "group": "b"},
             {"name": "b", "group": "b"},
             {"name": "c"}];


for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length - 1; i++){
  var a = array[i];
  if(!a.group){
    continue;
  }

  for(var j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
    var b = array[j];
    if(b.group === a.group){
      delete b.group;
    }
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there is more than two objects with the same `group` property

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var tmpObj = {};
tmpObj.name = array[j].name;
array.splice(j, 1, tmpObj);
```

It should remove the element with index j and add new object with only name.

Answer (score 1):

Just store all the group values you already have seen, and remove them if you see them again. Moreover, this will save you a loop.

```
var myArray = [...];

var existingGroups = [];

myArray.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.group){
        if(existingGroups.indexOf(item.group) === -1)
            existingGroups.push(item.group);
    else
        delete item.group;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a different approach:

Little explanation of the `if` condition:

`array.slice(0, i)`: we take only the previous elements of the array.

`.filter(v => v.group === val.group)` we see if they have the same value for property *group*.

`.length === 0)` If there is at least one element with the same value of group, we do not enter the if and return only the name, otherwise we return the value itself

```js
var array = [{"name": "a", "group": "a"},
             {"name": "a", "group": "a"},
             {"name": "b", "group": "b"},
             {"name": "b", "group": "b"},
             {"name": "c"}];

array = array.map((val, i) => {
  if (array.slice(0, i).filter(v => v.group === val.group).length === 0) {
    return val;
  }
  return {name: val.name};
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: same notice, If there are many properties other than only name .. It would be little difficult ? I mean this way?  @rpadovani

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code which might help:

```
var groups = {};
array.forEach(function(o) {
  if (groups[o.group]) {
    delete o.group;
  } else {
    groups[o.group] = true;
  }
})
```

You can also use more functional approach but you will need an additional utility library or have to implement some of the methods yourself.

```
var groups = array.map(function(o) { return o.group; }).unique();

groups
  .map(function(group) {
    return array.filter(function(o) { o.group == group }).slice(1);
  })
  .flatten()
  .forEach(function(o) { delete o.group });
```

flatten & unique are not included in the JavaScript spec.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need imbricated loops to do this. You can use `.forEach()` while keeping track of the groups that have been encountered so far. This can be done by using either the optional `thisArg` parameter or an explicit variable.

For instance:

```js
var array = [
  { "name": "a", "group": "a" },
  { "name": "a", "group": "a" },
  { "name": "b", "group": "b" },
  { "name": "b", "group": "b" },
  { "name": "c" }
];

var grp = {};

array.forEach(function(o) {
  grp[o.group] ? delete o.group : grp[o.group] = true;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: But if there are many properties other than only `name` .. It would be little difficult ? I mean this way?

Comment: @HalaElBarchah You are correct. Please see my updated answer.